# Add element into JSON Object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an JSON Object such as:

```
{result: 
   [ 
     { 
       "id": "1",
       "name": "name 1"
      },
      { 
       "id": "2",
       "name": "name 2"
      },
      { 
       "id": "3",
       "name": "name 3"
      }
  ]
}
```

I am wondering how can I add element (for example: "user":"username") into each object in this this JSON such as the result will come out:

```
{result: 
   [ 
     { 
       "id": "1",
       "name": "name 1",
       "user": "user 1"
      },
      { 
       "id": "2",
       "name": "name 2",
       "user": "user 2"
      },
      { 
       "id": "3",
       "name": "name 3",
       "user": "user 3"
      }
  ]
}
```

I was trying to do something like:

```
result.user = user.data
```

But it doesnt come out what I need. I am wondering if I can use a for loop such as

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  result.user = user.data;
}
```

Comment: If you're modifying it in this way, it isn't JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You're close ...

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  // result.user = user.data;
  result[i].user = "user " + (i + 1);
}
```

Essentially, result is an array of objects; you need to tell it which one to reference when accessing the internals.

Comment: Adjusted and commented out what was not needed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes use index of array . since you want `1` for 0th element so add 1 to index.
forEach will iterate over each array element . where a is the element and index is `a`th element index.

```js
var json={result: [ { "id": "1", "name": "name 1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "name 2" }, { "id": "3", "name": "name 3" } ] };
json["result"].forEach(function(a,index){
  a["user"]="user"+(index+1);
})
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Again: Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: just another hint, please use a different variable name if the content is not really a [JSON](http://json.org/) string. it looks like an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz isn't it json ?

Comment: **json is always a string**, not an object. it it not even a synonym for it.

Comment: @NinaScholz no i am serious. tell me na please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129892/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-mahi).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put this json in a variable, then you can interate the object acessing the result array.

```js
var object = {result: 
       [ 
         { 
           "id": "1",
           "name": "name 1",
           "user": "user 1"
          },
          { 
           "id": "2",
           "name": "name 2",
           "user": "user 2"
          },
          { 
           "id": "3",
           "name": "name 3",
           "user": "user 3"
          }
      ]
    };


for (var i = 0; i < object.result.length; i++) {
  object.result[i].user = "user " + i;
}

console.log(object);
```